# Format a date in Javascript without converting to local timezone

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, date, timezone

In an SQL database I have a list of times from different time zones but I neither have nor care for the corresponding time zone information:

```
2012-01-01 01:02:03
2012-07-01 04:05:06
```

For outputting I'd like to format them using Javascript. I tried:

```
var text = input.replace(' ','T'); // SQL -> ISO8601
var d = new Date(Date.parse(text));
hours = d.getHours();
```

The problem is that in Chrome the the date is interpreted as being in UTC and converted to my local time zone, so I get:

```
2
6
```

while in Firefox it's interpreted as local time and I get what I want:

```
1
4
```

So is there a better solution with the *Date* object or am I stuck with splitting the string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only solution I found is replacing `-` with `/`:

```
input = "2012-01-01 01:02:03";
var text = input.replace('-', '/');
var d = new Date(Date.parse(text));
hours = d.getHours();
```

In my case the input was `2013-05-22T16:45:00Z` so I replaced `T` and `Z` as well:

```
input = "2013-05-22T16:45:00Z";
var text = input.replace(/[TZ]/, '').replace('-', '/');
var d = new Date(Date.parse(text));
hours = d.getHours();
```

That way Javascript deals with it without knowing anything about timezone and stop acting smartly.

Comment: So in other cases with timezones, just remove it manually or by Regex

Comment: like here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348431/best-way-to-remove-edt-from-a-date-returned-via-javascript-with-tolocalestring

Comment: In Firefox `Date.parse("2013-05-22 16:45:00")` gives NaN.

Comment: replace the '-' with '/' using replace all command
`myDate = myDate.replace(/-/g,'/');`

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I rephrased your answer and made it the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you :) hope it was really useful and solved your problem. would vote me up  as well :) i'm trying to have some credit here

Answer (score 0):

I think that to do with Dates you will need to use some Date "framework" like [Globalize jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/) or [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) to get cross-browser behavior. Doing this, you will be able to configure a pattern to be used in the date parsing.